# switching colors between buttons get stuck on last color

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have 2 buttons, once a button is clicked - it should be come red and the other blue. Problem, the button cannot go back to blue color (if becomes red, it will not change).

my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpa50kc9/)

[image]

CSS

```
<div id='div-a'         class="btn btn-primary">btn A</div>
<div id='div-b'     class="btn btn-primary">btn B</div>
```

JS

```
    $( "#div-a" ).on( "click", function() {
        console.log("clicked A")
        
      $('#div-a').addClass('btn btn-danger');
      $('#div-b').addClass('btn btn-primary');
      
    }.bind(this));
    
    
    $( "#div-b" ).on( "click", function() {
      console.log("clicked B")
      
      $('#div-a').addClass('btn btn-primary');
      $('#div-b').addClass('btn btn-danger');
      
    }.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using `addClass()`. what this does is, appends the classes you pass. so when you add `btn btn-danger` to `#div-a` it's classList becomes like: `btn btn-success btn btn-danger`
and thus it does not override it.

to fix this, first remove the existing classes and then add classes.

so the total code rewritten would be:

```
  $( "#div-a" ).on( "click", function() {
        console.log("clicked A")

      $('#div-a').removeClass('btn-primary');
      $('#div-a').addClass('btn-danger');

      $('#div-b').removeClass('btn-danger');
      $('#div-b').addClass('btn-primary');
      
    }.bind(this));
    
    
    $( "#div-b" ).on( "click", function() {
      console.log("clicked B")
      
      $('#div-a').removeClass('btn-danger');
      $('#div-a').addClass('btn-primary');

      $('#div-b').removeClass('btn-primary');
      $('#div-b').addClass('btn-danger');
      
    }.bind(this));
```

And here is the link to working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kxbow9ct/

Comment: Much appreciated for the solution and the explanation.  @Adison Masih

Comment: @ProcolHarum Most Welcome